# Using a value type in strongly typed MVC view user control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got an MVC user control with the following basic structure:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Decimal>" %>

<%= Math.Round(Model) %>
```

Which gives this error message when I use it:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0452: The
>   type 'decimal' must be a reference
>   type in order to use it as parameter
>   'TModel' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl'

Is there a way to get this to work (somehow tricking the framework into treating the Decimal as a reference type maybe?) Or is what I'm trying to do just fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest you wrap the value type within a ViewModel. This will allow for some flexibility in the future (which may or may not be needed).

```
public class MyUserControlViewModel
{
    public Decimal MyValue { get; private set; }

    public MyUserControlViewModel(Decimal dec)
    {
        MyValue = dec;
    }
}


<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyUserControlViewModel>" %>

<%= Math.Round(Model.MyValue) %>
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't have to wrap into class, if you want a fast way, use this

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Nullable<Decimal>>" %>
```

also you can consider use

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
```

and validate by code

Answer (score 3):

`ViewUserControl` is declared as follows:

```
public class ViewUserControl<TModel> : ViewUserControl
where TModel : class
```

So you can't trick it into compiling with a value type. I'd recommend wrapping your `Decimal` object in another class.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the value in a class:

```
 public class Wrapper
{
        public Wrapper(decimal d)
        {
            this.Value = d;   
        }
        Decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

In the View:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Wrapper>" %>
<%= Math.Round(Model.Value) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The model is a DTO from the controller to the view. You should create your own DTO even with a single decimal property. The view's responsibility is only about rendering, the Math.Round should be executed by the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly familiar with the ASP.Net MVC Framework, but the error is saying your model has to be a class, not a primitive type, which is pretty standard from a model view controller perspective.

To get this to work, you'd need a class like:

```
class MyDouble : Model   // or whatever MVC calls it's Model
{
   public TheValue {
     get;
     set;
   }
}
```

and then replace your line with `<%= Math.Round(Model.TheValue) %>`.

Note, It seems like a strange design to have a custom control for just a double value.  If this is just a sample app, then fine, but otherwise, you may want to reconsider how to best use custom controls.

Comment: I am sorry but your example will not compile since the property "TheValue" has **NO** type.

Answer (score 0):

While I strongly support all the answers above, stating to wrap the decimal value in a class to support further development you can quickly solve your problem by making the decimal nullable ("decimal?") since System.Nullable is a reference type.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work either. I get the same error but with "Decimal?" instead of "Decimal"